# force:inputField lookup field with create new record option

Tags: lightning, css, component

I am using force:inputField to get account lookup field with `+ New Account` button with reference of https://www.infallibletechie.com/2018/03/lookup-field-with-option-to-create-new.html

But the lookup results section are fixed and not moving while scrolling the screen, Is there and CSS trick the make the result section position dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working perfectly after making parent div `position:relative`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471396/how-to-use-css-absolute-position-inside-a-scrollable-div-element)